# Class inheritance - add argument without rewriting parent constructor arguments

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6, subclass

I would like to extend the following class:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }
  
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
  
    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }
}
```

...by adding `sport` and its getter:

```
class Athlete extends Person {
    constructor(name, age, sport) {
        super();
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
        this._sport = sport;
    }
  
    get sport() {
        return this._sport;
    }
}
```

While the above works, I would like to **avoid repeating the arguments** of the base-parent constructor. The following approach won't work:

```
class Athlete extends Person {
    constructor(sport) {
        super();
        this._sport = sport;
    }
  
    get sport() {
        return this._sport;
    }
}

let athlete = new Athlete('Peter', 29, 'cricket');
console.log(athlete.name, athlete.age, athlete.sport); // name and age are not inherited, is returned 'undefined'
```

So, how can I add fields to the subClass without rewriting the ones of the base Class?

Comment: There is absolutely not a single valid reason for implementing `get` functionality, which implies protected properties, when everything **get**able is public. The underscore pseudo-privacy notation is of no help, since it will be circumvented at one day. Make every to be protected property a true private property, each with its own `get` functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be achieved (using [destructured parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments#rest_default_and_destructured_parameters) (`...args`) syntax to denote an arbitrary number of arguments), however, it is not advised (at least the way I did it), and it comes at certain costs, some of which are readability, ease of debugging, lesser error-prone code, and more (since this makes the code a little more obscure, making the order of the arguments not that clear and making it possible to pass the wrong number of arguments):

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }
  
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
  
    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }
}

class Athlete extends Person {
    constructor(...args) {
        let sport = args.pop();
        super(...args);
        this._sport = sport;
    }
    
    get sport() {
        return this._sport;
    }
}

let athlete = new Athlete('Peter', 29, 'cricket');
console.log(athlete.name, athlete.age, athlete.sport);
```

It can similarly be achieved using the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }
  
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
  
    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }
}

class Athlete extends Person {
    constructor() {
        let args = Array.from(arguments);
        let sport = args.pop();
        super(...args);
        this._sport = sport;
    }
    
    get sport() {
        return this._sport;
    }
}

let athlete = new Athlete('Peter', 29, 'cricket');
console.log(athlete.name, athlete.age, athlete.sport);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the arguments, but you can avoid to assign all of them by passing them to `super()`:

```
class Athlete extends Person {
    constructor(name, age, sport) {
        super(name, age); // pass arguments to super()
        this._sport = sport;
    }
  
    get sport() {
        return this._sport;
    }
}

let athlete = new Athlete('Peter', 29, 'cricket');
console.log(athlete.name, athlete.age, athlete.sport);
```

Comment: So, I still have to repeat `name`, `age`. I don't see what's the point of this repetition since they already exist in base class.

Comment: There are required because you want to call `new Athlete('Peter', 29, 'cricket')`, but you also want `constructor(sport)`. The signature of the functions are not the same. JS cannot decide by itself the where the argument needs to go.

Comment: Imagine you want `new Athlete('cricket', 'Peter', 29)`, how JS could know how to dispatch variables ?

Comment: if the sequence of the arguments is the problem, I suppose there could be a pattern like `[parent_arguments], child_argument_1, child_argument_2` instead of having to repeat all parent arguments.

Comment: Yes, you could pack parent's arguments, if you want, but you will loose the readability of your code. `constructor([parent_arguments], sport)` need to refer to the parent class, `constructor(name, age, sport)` can be read as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to add new args **before** the rest `...` operator:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }
  
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
  
    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }
}

class Athlete extends Person {
    constructor(sport, ...args) {
        super(...args);
        this._sport = sport;
    }
    
    get sport() {
        return this._sport;
    }
}

let athlete = new Athlete('cricket', 'Peter', 29);
console.log(athlete.name, athlete.age, athlete.sport);
```

This improves performance, but not necessarily readability, which shifts the weirdness from usage of functions that aren't usual to constructors to a random order.

BTW, would I recommend any of solutions listed here, including this one? Absolutely **not**, this is more of a "it can't be done nicely" informative question as of now.